# Docker run cannot find existing file?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, debian, vaapi

I am trying to run this command to test if the gpu is being recognized

```
docker run --rm --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri jrottenberg/ffmpeg:5.1.2-vaapi2004 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i /root/Server_transcoder/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normalORIG.mp4 -c:v h264_vaapi /tmp/example.mp4
```

And it errors out with: `/root/Server_transcoder/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normalORIG.mp4: No such file or directory`

The file exists in there and the path is not misspelled - I checked like 10 times

What could be the problem here?? I am clueless

Comment: It exists on your host, not in the container.

Comment: the file I placed is in a smb share inside the container (running bullseye debian), not on the host

Comment: and I can see the files in console if I navigate to the folders and do ls

Comment: Could you clarify how you're attaching the smb share to the container? And where do you do this step: "I can see the files in console if I navigate to the folders and do ls"? Is that on the host, the jrottenberg/ffmpeg:5.1.2-vaapi2004 container, or a third (?) bullseye debian container?

Comment: I do everything inside the lxc - smb, docker, everything. I do not interact with the host. The "I can see the files" is in the console of the lxc container where all this is happening - and jrottenberg/ffmpeg is only a docker image

Comment: You're not mounting any host files into the container (`docker run -v` option) and the container `/root` directory is probably empty.

Comment: thank you @DavidMaze - that was the issue - problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

the docker run command was missing a mounting option - and the file did not need an absolute path, just a relative one to the mounting folder

this command worked:

```
docker run --rm --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri -v /root/Server_transcoder:/tmp/workdir  jrottenberg/ffmpeg:5.1.2-vaapi2004 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normalORIG.mp4 -c:v h264_vaapi /tmp/example.mp4
```